# Proving that a limit doesn't exist question.

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $a - 1 < 0$ and $b > 0$.

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x^{a-1}(\sin(x))^b\cos(1/x) & \quad x ≠ 0 \\
            0 & \quad x = 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

I suspect that $\underset{x\to 0}{\lim}f(x)$ doesn't exist. But I don't know how to show it and l'hopital's rule cannot be used.

Comment: Hint: $\cos(1/x)$ is bounded near $0$.

Comment: Hint 2: $\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^b\to1$.

Comment: Following up on Jam's first comment: it seems that there is this epic battle going on between $x^{1-a}$ wanting to push things to infinity and $(\sin(x))^b$ wanting to push things to zero, with $\cos(1/x)$ just watching from the sideline, eating popcorn and nodding its head up and down. So who will win? Without computing anything I'd say it depends on which positive number is bigger: $1 - a$ or $b$

Comment: @Vincent Wonderfully engaging narrative; love it.